# How can get boolean user Input

Tags: java, boolean, logic

When I input in the program like this:

```
boolean a = (true & false) & true;
```

It's worked.

But when I input from the keyboard by using Scanner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean b = sc.nextBoolean();
```

It can't return the correct answer.

Is there any way that I can boolean when input from keyboard?
Sorry if my English isn't clearly.

Comment: What value are you typing?

Comment: The `Scanner` will accept a  _single_ boolean value of `true` or `false` (or any case-insensitive variants thereof, such as `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `True`, `False`, `trUe`, `fALse`, etc.).  It _won't` accept an entire boolean expression like `(true & false) & true`...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well, what you mean "value"? I just use System.out.println() to print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs of [`nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBoolean()), it would *scan the next token of the input into a boolean value and returns that value.*

So as rightly pointed out by @Kevin in the comments, if you try providing it an input other than the case-insensitive `true` or `false`, you would end up with an `InputMismatchException.`

Comment: Oh, I get it. Is there anyway that we can boolean when using user input? Thanks

Comment: @Jon You can provide an input of boolean value to `b` using scanner `sc`. But if the expression is already evaluated as in a line above, then you don't need to scan it for a user input.

Comment: @Jon If this answer solved your problem then please mark it as the accepted answer (click that tick sign beside thr answer). This will make this post helpful for future visitors.